# Overriding ofstream operator<<

Tags: c++

Why i still have **ERROR: exepected an identifier** in `std::ofstream << val` on the line below? msvc.

```cpp
std::ostream& operator<< (bool val) { m_lock.lock(); std::ofstream << val; m_lock.unlock(); return *this; }
```

```cpp
class OfstreamLog : public std::ofstream  {

    private:

        std::mutex m_lock;

    public:

        OfstreamLog() : std::ofstream() { }
        explicit OfstreamLog(const char* filename, ios_base::openmode mode = ios_base::out) : std::ofstream(filename, mode) { }

        std::ostream& operator<< (bool val) { m_lock.lock(); std::ofstream << val; m_lock.unlock(); return *this; }
        std::ostream& operator<< (short val);
        std::ostream& operator<< (unsigned short val);
        std::ostream& operator<< (int val);
        std::ostream& operator<< (unsigned int val);
        std::ostream& operator<< (long val);
        std::ostream& operator<< (unsigned long val);
        std::ostream& operator<< (float val);
        std::ostream& operator<< (double val);
        std::ostream& operator<< (long double val);
        std::ostream& operator<< (void* val);
        std::ostream& operator<< (std::streambuf* sb);
        std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& (*pf)(std::ostream&));
        std::ostream& operator<< (std::ios& (*pf)(std::ios&));
        std::ostream& operator<< (ios_base& (*pf)(ios_base&));

    };
```

Comment: Why would you want to override `<<`?

Comment: @Golazo: look at the code, i need to synchronize writing via operator <<

Comment: Off-topic, but consider using `std::lock_guard`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`std::ofstream` is a type name. You can't call a nonstatic method or operator for it without any object.

In this case you probably want `std::ofstream::operator<<(val);` instead of `std::ofstream << val;`.

---

**Explanation:**

When you want to call method of a parent class from method of a child class, you do it like this:

```
class A
{
    void func() {}
};

class B
{
    void test()
    {
        func(); // Like this
    }
};
```

But if child class have method with same name (more precisely, with same *signature* (it means, same name and argument types)), it will be called instead of parent's one. To explicitly call the method of the parent class, you can use this syntax:

```
class A {...};
class B
{
    void test()
    {
        A::func(); // Notice `A::`
    }
};
```

Now let's talk about operators. When you want to call an operator, you usually use an object name for it, like `object << 10;`. But when you want to call operator of a class (or it's parent) from a method of this class, you should use full `operator` syntax:

```
class A
{
    operator<<(int){}
};
class B
{
    void test()
    {
        operator<<(10); // <-----
        *this << 10; // Also you can do it like this
    }
};
```

Now, we combine these two techniques:
If child class have operator with same signature as parent's one and you want to call operator of the parent, you do it like this:

```
class A {...};
class B
{
    void test()
    {
        A::operator<<(10); // Notice `A::`
        *(A*)this << 10; // Also you can do it like this
    }
};
```